# How automatic post link on own FB page as page with PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i've a CentOS 64bit with PHP 5.3.3 on it.
The latest FB Sdk require the 5.4, but however i find impossible to post automatically on my FB page as a page a link (that is showed with image+title+description).

Mean: i'm am on php page, i have a link (which page got all correct og:tag) and a message, how can I use this 2 variable to make an automatic post?

I've already a FB App with ID. But i want to preserve my PHP 5.3.3

Comment: only the latest php sdk requires php 5.4, but you can still use simple CURL calls or another sdk.

Comment: Yes, but with CURL the token expire in the best way after 60 days... and facebook doesn't provide good documentation to post link in page... very poor and incomplete documentations...

Comment: that´s complete nonsense. even the php sdk uses CURL. you may need to read more about access tokens, the docs are VERY good nowadays.

Comment: Maybe you should read it in detail an put some effort in it yourself. There are probably tens of thousands of people which are using it successfully...

Comment: if you really can´t figure it out with the docs, here´s an article i wrote about the access tokens: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ - but in fact it´s mostly what´s in the official docs already, with some additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the documentation:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish

Comment: That's nonsense @user3849948